# Processing Programming Average Image

Tags: javascript, java, image, processing, computer-science

I just began learning to program within Processing and I am now working with images. I am trying to load an image, then create an average image when the key 'a' is pressed. I want a second image to be computed, where the pixels are all set to the average color, of the original image, over all the pixels in the image. Here's the code so far, but every time I press the 'a' key, I receive an error message.

```java
PImage inputimg = loadImage("dog.jpg");
boolean loadimg = false;

void setup() {
    size (400,400);
    background(255);
}

void draw() {
    image(inputimg,15,45);
}  

void keyPressed() {
    //for average color
    if(key == 'a' || key == 'A'){
        loadimg = true;
        inputimg.loadPixels();
        int red=0,green=0,blue=0;
        for(int i=0;i<inputimg.pixels.length;i++){
            color c = inputimg.pixels[i];
            red = red + (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
            green = green + (c >> 8) & 0xFF;
            blue = blue + (c >> 0) & 0xFF;
        }
        red = red / inputimg.pixels.length;
        green= green / inputimg.pixels.length;
        blue = blue / inputimg.pixels.length;

        inputimg.loadPixels();
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
                int update = j + i*width;
                pixels[update] = color(red,green,blue);
            }
        }
        updatePixels();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PImage.loadPixels` loads the pixels to the `.pixel` attribute of the [`PImage`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html) object. Change the `.pixel` of the image and use `PImage.updatePixels()` to store the pixel to the image. e.g:

```java
PImage inputimg;

void setup() {
    size (400,400);
    inputimg = loadImage("dog.jpg");
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    image(inputimg, 15, 45);
}  

void keyPressed() {

    if (key == 'a' || key == 'A'){
        inputimg.loadPixels();
        int red=0, green=0, blue=0;
        for(int i=0; i<inputimg.pixels.length; i++){
            color c = inputimg.pixels[i];
            red += (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
            green += (c >> 8) & 0xFF;
            blue += (c >> 0) & 0xFF;
        }
        red /= inputimg.pixels.length;
        green /= inputimg.pixels.length;
        blue /= inputimg.pixels.length;

        for(int i=0;i<inputimg.pixels.length;i++){
            inputimg.pixels[i] = color(red,green,blue);
        }
        inputimg.updatePixels();
    }
}
```